# How to apply by chunks a function to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I know that [apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function can be use to apply a function to a dataframe's column:

```
df.applymap(my_fun)
```

How can I apply `my_fun` by chunks?, for instance chunks of 1, 5, 10, and 20 rows?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC you can use [np.split()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) method:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
     a   b   c
0   66  64  76
1   74  15   8
2    1  29  45
3   88  98  55
4   73  24  39
5   43  86  54
6    3  10  99
7    7  36  87
8    2  26   2
9   26  49  82
10  16  38  79
11  93  78  23
12  47  35  70
13  10  47  65
14  98  81  67
15  81  13  14
16  25  47  33
17  94  48  66
18  80  52  90
19  43  40  32

In [6]: df.shape
Out[6]: (20, 3)

In [7]: [x.shape for x in np.split(df, [5, 10, 18])]
Out[7]: [(5, 3), (5, 3), (8, 3), (2, 3)]
```

or if you need evenly sized chunks:

```
In [10]: [x.shape for x in np.split(df, np.arange(5, len(df), 5))]
Out[10]: [(5, 3), (5, 3), (5, 3), (5, 3)]
```

Using `apply()` function:

```
In [15]: [x.apply(np.sum) for x in np.split(df, np.arange(5, len(df), 5))]
Out[15]:
[a    302
 b    230
 c    223
 dtype: int64, a     81
 b    207
 c    324
 dtype: int64, a    264
 b    279
 c    304
 dtype: int64, a    323
 b    200
 c    235
 dtype: int64]
```

> How does pandas apply a function?

Pandas applies given function to the given vector of values:

- it applies given function to the whole column vector (column by column) if `axis=0`
- it applies given function to the row vector (row by row) if `axis=1`

Comment: Thanks for the help Max, what I do not understand is once the dataframe is reshaped, how does the function is applied?..

Comment: @tumbleweed, i've extended my answer with a little example - please check

Comment: Thanks!, in addition how does pandas makes the application of the function?... one by one ?

Comment: @MaxU, can you please have a look? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466252/throttle-pandas-apply-when-using-an-api-call