# Merge two dataframes based on messy addresses column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes (one with 1.7 million London homes and another with 60,000 transactions over one year)

Both dataframes have addresses columns, but they are quite messy so I've concatenated them into one combined address column, I also have postcodes but they have been excluded from the combined address column.

I essentially need to perform a Vlookup operation to merge the 1.7 million homes into the 60,000 transactions dataframe, so I can get the internal area of all the homes that have been sold and establish price per sq ft of all of those transactions.

The difficult part is that there is no mutual consistent index between the dataframes, I have combined addresses columns in both dataframes, but these are still very messy to use as a match and the outcome just seems to give me NaN values after merging into the transactions dataframe. This is the code I have so far:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('London.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('HPI London 18.csv')
pricepersqft = df1.merge(df2, on='Combined Address', how='right')
```

I wonder if I need to somehow get it to custom match with postcode first, then with the house or flat number if the postcode has been matched?

Any ideas on how I can perform this operation correctly would be much appreciated.

Comment: In a similar thing (messy alumns names) I used  https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy  with some success. https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python

Comment: can you give an example of one the 'messy' addresses?  You're probably better off translating the addresses to some other format (in the USA I'd use the plat map but I'm sure London has something similar).

Comment: Perhaps use package `geopy` to first clean the addresses in some way.  Some code for that API can be found in 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466252/throttle-pandas-apply-when-using-an-api-call/53467257#53467257

Comment: Geocoding 1.7 million homes will take too long unfortunately

Comment: @JoshuaSmith - the messy addresses are due to hyphens used in some instances and commas in others, missing address information or only part of the address has been entered, typos in some cases too etc